# Значения полей не передаются в DTO

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-boot

Копаюсь в Котлине.

Есть у меня DTO.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
open class AbstractDto : Serializable {

    open var id: Long? = null
    open var created: LocalDateTime? = null
    open var updated: LocalDateTime? = null
}

open class UserDto : AbstractDto() {

    open var height: Int? = null
    open var weight: Double? = null
    open var gender: String? = null
    open var birthDate: LocalDateTime? = null
    open val contacts: List<ContactDto> = ArrayList()
}
```

Есть контроллер, он наследуется от абстрактного контроллера, а тот - от интерфейса (слишком сложно, согласен, но я решил с этим поиграть тоже):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@ControllerImpl
class UserController : AbstractController<User, UserDto, UserMapper, UserRepository, UserServiceImpl>()

open class AbstractController<
        E : AbstractEntity,
        D : AbstractDto,
        M : AbstractMapper<E, D>,
        R : CommonRepository<E>,
        S : AbstractService<E, D, M, R>
        > : CommonController<D> {

    private val service: S? = null

    override fun save(dto: D?): ResponseEntity<D> = ResponseEntity.ok(service!!.save(dto)!!)

    override fun update(dto: D): ResponseEntity<D> = ResponseEntity.ok(service!!.update(dto)!!)

    override fun get(id: Long): ResponseEntity<D> = ResponseEntity.ok(service!!.get(id)!!)

    override fun getAll(pageable: Pageable): ResponseEntity<Page<D>> = ResponseEntity.ok(service!!.getAll(pageable))

    override fun delete(id: Long): ResponseEntity<Boolean> = ResponseEntity.ok(service!!.delete(id))
}

interface CommonController<D : AbstractDto> {

    @PostMapping
    fun save(dto: D?): ResponseEntity<D>

    @PutMapping
    fun update(dto: D): ResponseEntity<D>

    @GetMapping("/all")
    fun get(id: Long): ResponseEntity<D>

    @GetMapping
    fun getAll(pageable: Pageable): ResponseEntity<Page<D>>

    @DeleteMapping
    fun delete(id: Long): ResponseEntity<Boolean>
}
```

Отправляю POST-запрос:

```
{
    "height": 180,
    "weight": 75,
    "user": 1
}
```

На контроллер приходит DTO, где все поля == null. Подскажите, что я сделал не так? Когда не было абстракции, все поля приходили норм.

Кроме Котлина, задействованы Spring Boot и, в части маппинга DTO в сущность и обратно, modelmapper. Но до него дело не доходит.

Comment: Кроме Котлина тут еще какой-то фрамеворк задействован. Уточните вопрос, добавьте нужные метки.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja добавил, но до маппера дело не доходит - приходит пустое на контроллер.